# Finding the equation of a plane given three points where the solution does not have $z$ in it

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Below is a problem that I made up. I believe that my solution is correct but the answer seems to simple to me. Is my solution correct?
Problem:
Find the equation of the plane containing the points $(1,1,1)$,
$(2,2,2)$ and $(2,2,3)$.
Answer:

\begin{align*} 
P1 &= (1,1,1) \\
P2 &=  (1,1,2) \\
P1 \times P2 &=
\begin{vmatrix}
 i & j & k \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
P1 \times P2 &= (2 - 1 )i - (2-1)j +  (1 - 1)k \\
P1 \times P2 &= i - j \\
(x-1) - (y-1) &= 0 \\
x - y &= 0
\end{align*}
Partial check, is the point $(2,2,3)$ on the plane?
$$ x - y = 2 - 2 = 0 $$.
It is.

Comment: It is the equation of a plane, it contains all three point, so it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is indeed correct. I suppose that you will agree that the expression $x-y=0$ defines *some* plane. But all of your points belong to the plane $x-y=0$. Since three non-colinear points define a plane, then the plane that you are interested in has to be the plane $x-y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is **not** a valid method; it worked in your case only because the plane passes through the origin. (You also have a typo. The first time you said $P_2 = (2,2,2)$. Note that if you'd used this point, the cross-product would have been $\vec 0$ to start with. Then what?) To convince yourself, try $P_1=(1,1,1)$, $P_2=(0,-1,3)$, $P_3=(2,3,4)$.

In general, to obtain the normal vector to the plane you must look at $(P_2-P_1)\times (P_3-P_1)$ or something analogous to that.

Comment: My solution is to compute $(P_2-P_1)\times (P_3-P_1)$. However, what I am calling $P_1$ is what you call $(P_2-P_1)$. What I am calling $P_2$ you call $P_3-P_1$. Therefore, I believe my solution is correct but notation could use some work. I am thinking I should have called it $V_1$ and $V_2$ instead of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you didn't change the second point, after all. Yes, please do not use $P_i$ for the difference vectors. So your method is, in fact, the standard method EXCEPT that you must clarify that at the last step you're plugging  back in one of the original *points* and not the difference vectors. Just way too many coincidences with your example and awkward notation :)